# Database Hangs while impdp "DATABASE_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER" at this stage

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, impdp, datapump

I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

i am facing issue while impdp on other server. it hangs at the last line message below. it takes min. over 2-3 hours to continue. while importing i can not  find any error message on  alert log file or no any lock . then why it is taking too much time for importing ?

```
 -***************-
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
```

here is my par file for impdp syntax :-

```
DIRECTORY=dir1
LOGFILE=abc_imp.LOG
DUMPFILE=abc.dmp
INCLUDE=SCHEMA:"IN('u1','u2','u3')"
include=role
content=METADATA_ONLY
TRANSFORM=SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES:N
```

please let me know if any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Known bug, still under investigation.

Workaround is to use `exclude=statistics`.

Comment: `DIRECTORY=dir1
LOGFILE=abc_imp.LOG
DUMPFILE=abc.dmp
INCLUDE=SCHEMA:"IN('u1','u2','u3')"
include=role
content=METADATA_ONLY
TRANSFORM=SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES:N
exclude=statistics`

Comment: Facing Error :- **UDI-00011: parameter include is incompatible with parameter exclude**

Comment: @vvs `EXCLUDE` and `INCLUDE` parameters are mutually exclusive. You can use `exclude=statistics` on export as well. Or you can create the roles, then run 3 seperate schema mode imports without the `include` parameter, which allows you to use `exclude=statistics` on import.

Comment: @ Balazs Papp thanks for the replay but in real time i have a number of schemas so it is not possible to do every time & also they all Schemas have dependency on each other

Comment: @vvs Then you can use the `schemas=u1,u2,u3` parameter for performing schema mode import.

Comment: with schemas=u1,u2,u3 is worked thanks for this , but for instance i have to remove this " include=role " from parameter file to avoid error .Lets i had started once it completed & let you know . Thanks once again